# How do programatically invoke navigate event for Kendo Ui Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I would like to move the placement of the toolbar controls to outside of the scheduler block.
[image: Like this]

How would one go about invoking the same commands the next and previous buttons do from the toolbar but on my own custom button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the code snippet below.

In the code, I increase or decrease the 'date' part of the current date by 1 and then feed it back to the scheduler. It works automatically with the end or start of the month and year.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/events">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css">
    <script src="../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
  <button onclick="prev()">Previous</button>
  <button onclick="next()">Next</button>

  <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
<script>
  $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    dataSource: [
      {
        id: 1,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
        title: "Interview"
      }
    ]
  });
  
  function next() {
    let scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    let date = scheduler.date();
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
   scheduler.date(date);
  }
  
  function prev() {
    let scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    let date = scheduler.date();
   date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
   scheduler.date(date);
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yep, this is the one, If I increment the month it does exactly what I want it to.